# Any Suggestion Timelimit Verdict on My Code

Tags: c, optimization

Jojo and his friends have a list of N spot on a mountain range.
(There is a professional mountain climber group that divide the mountain range into N strategic points)
If someone want to climb this mountain range, it always starts at the first point. We can say ”Climb Up”
if we go from lower altitude point to the higher ones and ”Climb Down” otherwise.
Jojo and his friends want you to find how long is the range to get exactly K ”Climb Up” and M ”Climb Down”?

Input consists of one integer T, the number of test case. For each test case, it contains 3 integers N, K, M - number of points on the mountain range, number of ”Climb Up”, and number of ”Climb Down” for this expedition. The next line contains N integers Ai - the altitude for every point on the mountain range.

Output should be expressed in format ”Case #X: Y ” - X is the number of test case,
and followed by Y - minimum length of the range such fulfill the criterion above.

I have written a code
My sample code is as follows

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int T;
    scanf("%d",&T);
    for(int i=0;i<T;i++){
        int N,K,M;
        scanf("%d %d %d",&N,&K,&M);
        int alt [N];
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
            scanf("%d",&alt[i]);
        }
        int ans = 2147483647;
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
            int up=0,down=0,range=0;
            for(int j=i+1;j<N;j++){
                if(alt[j]>alt[j-1]){
                    up++;
                    range++;
                }
                else{
                    down++;
                    range++;
                }  
                if(up==K && down==M && range<ans){   
                    ans = range+1;
                    break;
                }
                else if(up>K || down>M){
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if(ans==2147483647){
            ans = -1;
        }
        printf("Case #%d: %d \n",i+1,ans);   
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So just help me with this question "Can I optimize that Code?"

Comment: If your code is working as you expect and you want a review this is the wrong site - use https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: It very likely can, but it is unclear what you mean by *"find how long is the range to get exactly K ”Climb Up” and M ”Climb Down”?"*. For working code (as yours appears to be), your question is more properly asked on [CodeReview.StackExchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I did suggest https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for review. However, I'm not sure your code is doing what it is supposed to do. The code seems to assume that you always move forward (i.e. alt[0] -> alt[1] -> alt[2] -> ...). Are you sure that's correct? Why not do alt[0] -> alt[1] -> alt[0] -> alt[1] -> alt[2] ?